# Is it possible to create an artificial bee hive?

Tags: terraria

I play Terraria with a 1.2 generated world. It has a lizhard temple but it doesn't have any bee hive, so I need a way to create it, with or without map editing tools like TEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can import a hive wand, some hive blocks, hive walls and many buckets of honey you can sort of build a hive, but it will not contain a Queen Bee summoning object. If you just want to fight the Queen Bee for her drops, you can create an [Abeemination](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Abeemination) with imported or cheated-in materials and use it to summon her.

Comment: I want to build bee hive for hive walls.also I want to bee spawn when you mine hive blocks.so there is no way...

Comment: @mpower I believe mining hive blocks placed with a hive wand will spawn bees. As for hive walls, you can just cheat them in using TEdit.